# Can't access variables in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object called team.

console.log(team):

```
Object
    name: "School name"
    opa: 203
    opf: 230
    rri: 2429
    town: "Hometown"
    __proto__: Object
```

Looks good.   I can access the school name just fine:

console.log(team.name):

```
School name
```

But if I try to access any of the number variables…

console.log(team.opa):

```
0
```

They all print "0".  The program was outputting the right variables before and it just stopped after I made some unrelated changes, and now I can't seem to access those variables no matter what I try.  I tried a few different browsers and it happens in all of them.  I'm at a loss at how to further debug this issue.

Also, if I do something like

```
team.opa = 76;
```

I can access that 76 just fine, but it does not change the value of anything in "team".

Comment: If it "just stopped after you made some unrelated changes" then those changes weren't unrelated. Show us more code or revert your changes.

Comment: That isn't plain vanilla JavaScript syntax. Is it perhaps ActionScript?

Comment: What does `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( team, 'opa' )` reveal? Sounds like those properties may have a custom getter/setter defined or are not writable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not waiting for the AJAX request to finish before you start logging the objects, which means that the objects that are written to console are overwritten once the AJAX request is finished (objects that you `console.log` are dynamic and can change even after you logged them; this isn't true for scalar values though).

Instead, try this in your logging loop:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(teams[id], null, 2));
```

But ultimately, you need to move your entire logging loop (or whatever you want to do with the `teams` array) to *inside* the `$.get()` callback.

Comment: Yes!   Thank you.  One of the changes I made was to remove the "jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});" line because what I was using it for was no longer needed, but now I see I still needed it for a different reason.  After I added it back in, the script worked again.